# I am unable to drop a column from DB2 table

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-cloud, db2-luw

I am trying to drop a column from my DB2 table.

- Table name = `Instructor`
- Column name is `Page`

Command used is:

```
ALTER TABLE instructor 
DROP COLUMN page;
```

I am getting this error

> Column, attribute, or period "PAGE" is not defined in "GFQ70186.INSTRUCTOR".. SQLCODE=-205, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.25.1301

Please help me to understand this error

Comment: Do you have multiple `instructor` tables in different schema's?

Comment: No..  I just have one table.  I am able to add columns to this table but unable to drop any columns.

Comment: Can you check your column 'Page' has any Check?

Comment: The Page column has a CHECK constraint, therefore, you cannot delete it.

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQL Server? That doesn't look like a SQL Server error. (My searchfu suggests it's a DB2 error.)

Comment: Yes.. I am using DB2 on cloud.

Comment: Then why tag SQL Server and it's CLI `sqlcmd`? If you're using DB2, tag `db2`, not a completely unrelated DBMS.

Comment: Did you try `drop column "Page"` ?

Comment: What's the exact result of `SELECT COLNAME FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABSCHEMA='GFQ70186' AND TABNAME='INSTRUCTOR' AND UPPER(COLNAME)='PAGE'`?

Answer (score 1):

If your column name is `Page` (i.e. with a capital `P` and lower case `age`) then you will need to use double quotes

```
ALTER TABLE INSTRUCTOR
DROP COLUMN "Page"
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000720.html

Ordinary identifier:

> An ordinary identifier is an uppercase letter followed by zero or more characters, each of which is an uppercase letter, a digit, or the underscore character. **Note that lowercase letters can be used when specifying an ordinary identifier, but they are converted to uppercase when processed**

Delimited identifier:

> A delimited identifier is a sequence of one or more characters enclosed by double quotation marks. Leading blanks in the sequence are significant. A delimited identifier can be used when the sequence of characters does not qualify as an ordinary identifier. **In this way an identifier can include lowercase letter**